# More efficient way of comparing datetimes in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

We have a *yuge* table in a remote Oracle database that I use mainly to export data to our local sql server database. Just to give you an idea, I tried doing a simple row count for the purpose of this post and it hasn't returned a value after 10 minutes.

One of the columns in this table is of type datetime (conveniently called `DATETIME`). So my query will get the daily `SUM` of columns `SAUTO` and `SMAN` for every day between yesterday and 8 days ago, for example.

These are a few of the queries that I've tested:

```
SELECT trunc(datetime)
  ,TransId
  ,sum(SAUTO)
  ,sum(SMAN)
  ,count(TransId)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE     
  and trunc(DATETIME) >= trunc(sysdate)-8
  and trunc(DATETIME) < trunc(sysdate)
  group by trunc(DATETIME), TransId
```

And:

```
SELECT 
CAST( to_char(DATETIME,'YYYYMMDD') AS int )
,TransId
,sum(SAUTO)
,sum(SMAN)
,count(TransId)
FROM MyTable
WHERE     
CAST( to_char(DATETIME,'YYYYMMDD') AS int ) >= CAST( to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') AS int ) - 8
and CAST( to_char(DATETIME,'YYYYMMDD') AS int ) < CAST( to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') AS int )
group by CAST( to_char(DATETIME,'YYYYMMDD') AS int ), TransId
```

Both return data (although the latter is much slower), but there has to be a more efficient way of checking this. Also, the DBA told me that column `DATETIME` uses partition pruning, if that helps any.

Finally, I only have read access to this table, so please, no suggestions on table schema improvements. You would just be wasting time and energy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> "the DBA told me that column DATETIME uses partition pruning"

So the table is partitioned by `DATETIME`. In which case it's a jolly bad idea to truncate that column in the WHERE clause, as that will disable partition pruning (the partition key is `DATETIME` not `trunc(DATETIME)`.

So this should be faster for you:

```
  SELECT trunc(datetime)
       ,TransId
       ,sum(SAUTO)
       ,sum(SMAN)
       ,count(TransId)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE DATETIME >= trunc(sysdate)-8
  and DATETIME < trunc(sysdate)
  group by trunc(DATETIME), TransId
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why do you need `+ 86399/86400`? If it's possibly related to retrieving data from today, then I've edited the question; it's the sum of everything between the day before yesterday and 8 days ago.

Comment: @AlexPoole - you're both right. I saw `<=` not `<`. Fixed it

Comment: Lets stop guessing and get some diagnostics - this will determine if partition pruning is occurring; after running you query, can you get the execution plan. Use this: select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'TYPICAL' ) )